# Number of 5-cycles and 6-cycles in a simple graph

Tags: graphs

Is there any formula for computing the number of 5-cycles and 6-cycles in a simple undirected graph?

Comment: You can obtain a formula by considering the cycle polynomial, but this isn't very practical since such expressions are usually of exponential size.  An algorithm to count might be a better idea.

Comment: Depends on what you consider to be a "formula".  Does an algorithm with five (or six) nested for-loops count?

Comment: Where does this come from? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

I'll suppose that you looking for $k$ *-cycle*, and in the following $f(k)$ is a computable function which belongs to $O(k!)$.

One simple algorithm is considering all possible k+1 vertices, to check whether they are part of a some cycle or not, this algorithm is $O(|V|^{k+1})$ (If we consider corresponding edge, running time can be improved on sparse graphs). This idea can be improved by using matrix multiplication algorithm, we know that in the level $m$ of (adjacency) matrix multiplication we have the number of paths of length $m$ starting from each node. Then we can calculate $M^k$, this can be done in $O(f(k)\cdot M^{\omega+1})$ (where $M^\omega$ is the lower bound for running time of matrix multiplication for adjacency matrix $M$ of input graph). But converting this to a cycle is a little bit tricky task and you can find one algorithm [here](http://www2.cs.upb.de/cs/ag-monien/PUBLICATIONS/POSTSCRIPTS/BMonien-HTFLPE1985.pdf), running time of exponential part still is independent of size of graph and is depend to $f$, but sure in the cycle case $f$ is bigger ($k!$ in the first paper). There are faster but more complicated algorithms like what described in [this](http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/ayz4.pdf), all of them are consequence of these simple ideas.

<sub>P.S: I hope to be clear that the bound that I mentioned is not tight, e.g in both Monien and Alan's papers, upper bounds are better than general thing that I wrote.</sub>

Comment: Is $\alpha$ the exponent for matrix multiplication? Maybe $\omega$ is the more commonly used symbol, but nevertheless you could define it.

Comment: @Juho, Actually I wasn't care about the running time of matrix multiplication, because of this I wrote $\alpha$, I just want to say that there is a polynomial function that we can use (independent of k, or it's fixed parameter tractable), bye the way I edited the answer to reflect your comment, seems it was confusing for readers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Let $M$ denote the adjacency matrix of the graph.  You can compute $M' = M^5$ (the 5th power of $M$) efficiently.  Now $M'_{i,i}$ counts the number of paths of length 5 starting at $i$ and ending at $i$.  Therefore, $\sum_i M'_{i,i}$ counts the number of 5-cycles, if you don't restrict these to be simple cycles.

If you want the number of simple cycles, you'll need to subtract off something to account for non-simple paths.  This is trickier, but can still be done using inclusion-exclusion and a case analysis.